# How to do a search by date query on cq pages

Tags: aem

I am trying to create a blog in cq5. The OOTB search component in blog is not supporting search by date feature. I tried to override it, but could not find the correct query to fetch the blogs created on a particular date. Seems the only functions supported are >,>=,<,<=.

Please help me in finding a query (preferabbly xpath) to fetch a page created on a particular date (cq:lastModified).

Comment: What type of query are you looking for SQL2, XPath, PredicateGroup? The syntax differs quite a bit between them.

Comment: I am looking for a XPath query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some functions in XPath like `contains` or `not`. There is also one for date fields. Here an example for anything that was just modified in the content tree:

```
/jcr:root/content//*[@cq:lastModified >= xs:dateTime('2015-05-29T08:44:56.280Z')]
```

Comment: But this will return me all the pages modifies after the specified time. I wnt jus that one page. So we cannot have a '=' functionality is it?

Comment: I think = or == would work as well, but then the dates have to be exactly the same down to the millisecond.

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas. By the way i am very new to this topic. I would like to explore more on querying JCR. Can you please suggest me any links for Xpath,SQL and Predicate Group querying?

Comment: The official docs are not bad. https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html For Xpath I would start with generic stuff like it is used in XSLT, before diging into the special cases within CQ: https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/crx/2-3/developing/searching_in_crx.html